# Adding info to devices in linux for libudev

Tags: linux

Hi how can i add additional info for my plugged device. eg /dev/ttyUSB0

say:

Vendor:
Device Type: 
Subsystem:

More importantly i want to add the device type. how can i do this or is this even possible?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set device properties using udev. It only gets devices properties and can do actions based on them (like if serial nr is xxxx then set it as eth0).

Comment: So it's impossible to modify the properties of a plugged device?.. like editing it as a normal file?.. say opening the properties file then modifying some text?.. because in libudev i'm always getting a "unable to find parent usb device. i replaced hidraw to tty
udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(mon, "tty", NULL);

udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "tty");
dev = udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype(
         dev,
         "usb",
         "usb_device");

unable to find parent usb_device in /dev/ttyS0?.. it should only detect dev/ttyUSB0 which is my usb device?

Comment: @demic0de: in Linux every device is a file. So for example you can (if you have privileges) open disk as a file and modify raw bytes (e.g. change partition table). But modifying properties should be done in kernel level or even firmware of devices.